# Java MergeSort Binary files

Tags: java, io

I have several sorted binary files which store information in some variable length format (meaning one of the segments contains the length of the variable length segment).

I need to merge them into one sorted file. I can do so with BufferedInputStream successfully. Nevertheless, it takes very long time on a mechanical disk. On a machine with SSD its much faster, as expected.

What bothers me is the fact that even on SSD, the CPU utilization is very low, and makes me suspect there's a way to improve the speed. I assume this happens because most of the time the CPU waits on the disk. I tried to increase the buffers to hundreds of MBs to no avail.

I have tried to use MemoryMapped buffer and file channel but it didn't improve the runtime.

Any ideas?

Edit: Using MemoryMappedByteBuffer failed because the merged file size is over 2 GB, which is the size limitation of MemoryMappedByteBuffer. But even before having merged the smaller files into GB files, I didn't notice an improvement in speed or CPU utilization.

Thanks

Comment: What about multi threading!? With an SSD it should be an improvement if your algorithm allows for multiple files to be processed simultaneously.

Comment: The program will run on a machine with a mechanical disk. It was a mistake by me to test and optimize it on a machine with a different type of disk.

Comment: If you write a program to just read through the files, writing them to the output, without sorting, is it any faster? If not, your bottleneck is the I/O. You can even test it outside Java - in UNIX `time cat input1 input2 input3 > output`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can compress the files better or is that not an option? If the bottleneck is I/O then reducing the amount is a good attack angle. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html

Comment: I can't compress the data further as it will need to run search operations on it while stored in the disk. It is compressed using several loss-less data compression methods.